# Django Admin Million Data - Admin page takes too long to open

Tags: python, django

I have a million lines of data on my website. I am very waiting when I want to reach this page via admin. Maybe 40-50 seconds. I did the pagination 20, but nothing changed. Currently the default is 100.

Its my admin code

```python
@admin.register(PollVote)
class PollVoteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['poll','referer','vote','ip', 'created_date']
    ordering = ('-created_date',)
    search_fields = ['ip']
    raw_id_fields = ['poll']
```

What can I do to speed up this page in Admin?

PollVote model:

```python
class PollVote(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name="Poll Name",related_name="votes")
    author = models.CharField(max_length=150,blank=True,verbose_name="Username")
    vote = models.TextField(verbose_name='Vote')
    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(protocol="IPv4")
    cookie = models.TextField(verbose_name="Voters' Cookie")
    votecount = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Vote Count",default=1,blank=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,verbose_name="Created Date")
    country_code = models.CharField(max_length=10,blank=True,verbose_name="Country Code")
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, verbose_name="Country")
    city = models.TextField(max_length=50, blank=True, verbose_name="City")
    vote_duration = models.FloatField(default=0, verbose_name="Vote Duration")
    referer = models.TextField(verbose_name='Referer', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.author
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['poll']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely because of an *N+1 problem* where it first will retrieve all the `PollVOte` objects, and *then* it has to make *N* queries to load the `title`s.

We can use the [**`list_select_related`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_select_related) option to add these to the [**`.select_related(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) items that will then be fetched in the same query:

```
@admin.register(PollVote)
class PollVoteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['title', 'referer', 'vote', 'ip', 'created_date']
    ordering = ('-created_date',)
    search_fields = ['ip']
    raw_id_fields = ['title']
    list_select_related = ['title']
```

It might be better however to rename the `ForeignKey` to the `Poll` model to `Poll`, *not* `title`, since `title` would hint towards a `CharField`.

Comment: thanks for help. This has reduced the time a bit but still runs very slowly. Any idea?

Comment: @Aytek: you can take a look at [`django-debug-toolbar`](https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar) to detect sources of large amounts of queries (N+1 problems).

Comment: now first page open super fast. but problem continue pagitation pages 2-3-... But its enoght for me. Your best thank you so much.